# Optimal way to bind two hashes

Tags: hash, sha-256, sha-1

Currently I have:

```
H1 = SHA256

H2 = SHA1
```

Both H1 and H2 have fixed length. What's the most efficient way to bind H1 and H2 together into H3? The goal is to maximize protection in case when one of them leaks.

For example:

1. `H3 = H1+H2`
2. `H3 = SHA512(H1+H2)`
3. `H3 = ???`

Length preserving is not needed. This should be calculated instantly so no KDF.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:** I plan to use it as password creation scheme. H1 and H2 should not be changed.

Comment: You've said what your goal _isn't_ (password storage); can you say what your goal _is_?

Comment: I'm sorry. Let's say it's password creation scheme.

Comment: I see no problem with either of your proposals, but it would depend on what you intend to do and what H1, H2 are in your use case... if they are supposed to be kept secret (passwords), just go for the SHA512 or another round of SHA-256.

Comment: @indiscreteLogarithm yes, secrecy would be an advantage. I wonder how SHA512 strength look like in case when one of H1,H2 will leak.

Comment: this would depend on the lengths of H1,H2 and if the sum of both lengths (H1&H2) is known.

Comment: My main concern is if I can do significantly better than H3 = H1+H2.

Comment: You want to maximize the protection against *what* exactly?

Comment: I already wrote that in my question: "The goal is to maximize protection in case when one of them (H1,H2) leaks.
".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If H1 becomes known then the first part of H3 becomes known if you just concatenate, so that's not a good option.

A simple XOR could work as long as H2 remains secret to an attacker. However, if info about H3 can be retrieved by an attacker and H1 can be changed then the attacker can force H3 to a certain value. But XOR doesn't expand the hash value as you seem to require.

If H1 and H2 are hashed together, e.g. with a larger output hash then all the attacker can do is to try and change H1 until some kind of structure appears in H3. This is the best thing to do if you just rely on hash functions.

---

You state that you don't require a KDF because you're not dealing with passwords. This is however not a good argument; there are also KBKDF's that derive output key material from input key material (and do not deal with passwords).

HKDF is a KDF that does this: it takes input key material, extracts the entropy from H1 and H2 into a certain intermediate key material, and finally expands the key material to the requested size. So the most fireproof way of creating H3 is: `H3 = HKDF(enc(H1, H2), "H3", outsize)`. Optionally you can also supply a salt or change the label (`"H3"`) to create different output values. `enc` is an encoding of the values H1 and H2, it can be just concatenation **if** the size of H1 and H2 can never change.

HKDF just relies on HMAC, and HMAC just relies on a secure hash function. So it can generally be implemented even if it is not directly available.

---

But just SHA-512 will also work.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Just one more question: does SHA512 really help in comparison to concatenation when by knowing H1 you can bruteforce H2 the same way? Additional cost would be only single SHA512 iteration.

Comment: That depends on how H3 is used; the use case is missing from your question. Say that H3 gets split up in two sections: then one section consists mainly of H1. Besides that being a problem in itself, it could also be that only part of H2 is mixed with H1. When bringing together two hashes you do really want to mix the randomness from one hash with the other hash, and concatenation is not a good idea in that case.

Comment: Well, I explicitly stated that it will be used as password creation scheme where H3 = password. H1 and H2 will be always bind together in the same form.

Comment: H3 will **not** be a password. You could use it as a secret that needs to be send / compared directly, but a password consists of printable characters. Possibly you could convert it to a password, but it will be a pretty complex one to store 512 bits of "random" data. I'd play it safe and use the SHA-512 hash though.

Comment: Yeah, I meant when using SHA512 or concatenation then H3 could be used as password directly otherwise i have to transform it. Anyway thank you for those answers.

Answer (score -1):

I would do the following to hide the output of either hash function (and prevent a flaw in one algorithm from compromising everything):

$H_1$ = SHA2-256( $secret_1$ )

$H_2$ = SHA**3**-256( $secret_2$ )

$H_3$ = $H_1$ $\oplus$ $H_2$

If you don't have access to SHA3-256 then using SHA2-256 on $secret_2$ should still be reasonable.

Comment: Thanks. I can't change H1 and H2 and I don't have access to SHA3.